# Getting count of total present and absent in single sql query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Here is my attendance table details `Emp_ID(varchar),pdate(datetime),attendance(char(2))`

[image]

i want to get the total count of attendence days ,total count of absent and total count of present in a **single query** for a particular date range grouping by `emp_id`

Comment: Well, what are you waiting for? go for it! (in other words - what have you tried so far?)

Comment: Google group by. Have fun

Comment: @ Zohar Peled : how to get the total count of absent and total count of present what should i use a suquery or case statement??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this worked for me.

```
select Emp_ID
      ,count(case when status ='A'  then 1 end) as absent_count
      ,count(case when status ='P' then 1 end) as present_count
      ,count(distinct pdate) as Tot_count
  from MASTERPROCESSDAILYDATA where pdate between '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-31' 
 group 
    by Emp_ID ;
```

Answer (score 3):

just an sample example to show you how to proceed with your data

```
declare @t table (id int,da date,attend Varchar(2))
insert into @t (id,da,attend) values (1,'20141011','P'),
 (1,'20141012','A'),
  (1,'20141013','P'),
   (1,'20141014','A'),
   (1,'20141014','P')

   select ID,COUNT(da)Total,
   (select COUNT(da) from @t where attend = 'A')as Absent,
   (select COUNT(da) from @t where attend = 'P')as Present from @t
   group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like that

```
SELECT Emp_id, present, absent FROM details
NATURAL JOIN(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS present FROM details WHERE Emp_id = table.Emp_id AND attendence='P' 
JOIN
SELECT COUNT(*) AS absent FROM details WHERE Emp_id = table.Emp_id AND attendence='A' ) AS ctt
```

Comment: Natural Join? Don't think that's sql-server

Answer (score 1):

You could use group by, as already demonstrated.

Or you can use window functions/analytic functions.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Emp_id INT,pdate DATE,attendance VARCHAR(2))
INSERT INTO @t (emp_id,pdate,attendance) VALUES (1,'20141011','P'),
 (1,'20141012','A'),
 (1,'20141013','P'),
 (1,'20141014','A'),
 (1,'20141014','P')


SELECT 
    DISTINCT
    EMP_ID,
    Attendance,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY attendance) as CntAttendance
FROM 
    @t
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the script below;

```
select id,
       count(distinct pdate) as Total_Attendance_Days,
       sum(case when attendance= 'p' then 1 else 0 end) Presents,
      sum(case when att = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) Absents
from ##TT
where pdate between '01/04/2015' and '15/04/2015'
group by id
```

Hope this helps